# Most pythonic way to handle both (1) general properties of a type of object with (2) individual properties of an instance of that object

Tags: python, class, coding-style

First a general explanation, and then what I am actually working on: Let say you have a group of apples. Some properties could be shared, such as `type = "Green Apple"` and `picked_date = "Aug 12 2012"`, but other data could be different between apples, such as `is_bruised` and `weight` or `size`. What is the most pythonic way to have *editable* values shared between apples such as `type` but also have individual attributes for each apple in the group? Coming from `C`, `C++`, my first instinct is a general struct, and a struct for each apple with a pointer to the general struct, as it seems silly for each apple instance to contain the group information, because if I wanted `type = "Red Apple"` I'd have to iterate though all the apples to edit their `type` value, which is a waste of programming power.

In real code, on my current work project, I am currently working on a git script to help parse output in a way that makes sense for my company. I have been reading up on (a) lists, (b) tuples, (c) dictionaries, and (d) classes in python, and I am really stuck trying to figure out the best way to represent this data.

To be specific, I am handling git commits, and there are two types of values I am concerned with: general properties shared between all commits, such as "do I print out the author of the commit?", and specific properties such as "commit x has author y". My current solution is inelegant:

```
class Commit(object):
    def __init__(self, author="", committer="", date="", issue="",
                 instruction="", message="", review="", sha="", short=""):
        self.author = author     
        self.committer = committer   
        self.date = date  
        self.instruction = instruction         
        self.issue = issue
        self.message = message
        self.review = review           
        self.sha = sha
        self.short = short
```

This class contains the data associated with a specific commit. Now, the data for all commits is stored as such:

```
 Attribute = namedtuple('Attribute', ['display', 'critical'])

 commit_attr = {'author': Attribute(display = True, critical = True),
                'committer': Attribute(display = True, critical = True),
                'date': Attribute(display = False, critical = False),
                'instruction': Attribute(display = True, critical = False),
                'issue': Attribute(display = True, critical = False),
                'message': Attribute(display = True, critical = False),
                'review': Attribute(display = True, critical = False),
                'sha': Attribute(display = True, critical = True),
                'short': Attribute(display = True, critical = True)}
```

Which is a dictionary with named tuples for the fields. "Critical" indicates if that field is required in a commit for it to be shown, display is used to determine if it should be printed or not.

Here's my problem: I know that related data in python should be grouped in a coherent method, but I don't know how to do that here: I could have a "pointer", such as `self.attr =  commit_attr` in the `Commit()` class, but this isn't very clean and would depend on that object keeping its address, i.e. being mutable, otherwise if I changed the value of the general attributes it would no longer be associated with the `Commit()` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this will be helpful to you, but Python has class attributes, which are shared between class instances:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   foo = 'bar'  # Notice that this isn't in an __init__ function definition
... 
>>> a = A()        # Just creating two distinct instances of A
>>> b = A()
>>> A.foo = 'baz'  # Now, I'm setting the class attribute
>>> b.foo
'baz'              # Notice how all instances of A changed
>>> a.foo
'baz'
>>>
```

Editing the class attribute affects all instances at once.

Comment: **Edited: Cool, that is exactly what I want, I think. The key here is to edit the class attribute from the class, instead of the instance right? E.g. if I do `a.foo = 'baz'` then `b.foo` is still `'bar'`

Comment: I wrote `A`, not `a`, when setting the *class* attribute (my variable names are bad, sorry). It doesn't work on instances. You're modifying the class.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you very much. For others looking for more information, I found some [here](http://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/courses/python/class/5/#classinst)